# MoviePy Exec() not working, syntax error?

Tags: python, moviepy, instagrapi

I am trying to have instagrapi automatically upload pictures and videos to instagram and I am having an issue.

I am trying the clip_upload() function and it isn't working.
This is the error I get:

```
    exec("from %s import %s" % (name, name))
  File "<string>", line 1
    from __init__ 2 import __init__ 2

                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*The carat points at the 2 after **init***

```
import pkgutil

import moviepy.video.fx as fx

__all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(fx.__path__) if name != "all"]


for name in __all__:
    exec("from %s import %s" % (name, name))
```

The Exec line is creating the issue when clip_upload()  is called:

```
if media_type == 2 and product_type == 'clips':      #Reel
   client.clip_upload(uploadPath, caption)
```

Comment: Indeed, the syntax `from __init__ 2 import __init__ 2` is invalid. `__init__ 2` is not a valid name as it contains a space. I don't know why `name`'s value is `'__init__ 2'`, but that's the issue. Why do you think it has to be that value?

Comment: Show us your code.  We can't tell anything from this.

Comment: I can paste my entire code into the post if that'll help.